# Using Dataframe with qframe and NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql, dataframe, go, qframe

I am trying to load a SELECT database statement into a qframe DataFrame.
Unfortunetely, I am getting errors due to NULL values in the database.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"

    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"

    "github.com/tobgu/qframe"

    qsql "github.com/tobgu/qframe/config/sql"
)


func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://login:password@url/db?sslmode=disable")
    
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    tx, _ := db.Begin()

    newQf := qframe.ReadSQL(tx,
        
        // orcamento_id is the table being queried
        qsql.Query("SELECT * FROM orcamento_item WHERE orcamento_id = 2"),

        qsql.Postgres(),
    )

    fmt.Println(newQf)
    tx.Commit()

}
```

I get the following error:

ReadSQL Scan: sql: Scan error on column index 5, name "item_ref_id": Column Null: non-nullable type: int

PS: I also dont know how to format very well this post, sorry...